# How to use sql executeQuery method in groovy?

Tags: sql, groovy

In groovy how can i use sql executeQuery method. In my below code i get the error as "Method executeQuery is protected in groovy.sql.Sql" on line 2. Please help!

```
def sql = new Sql(rdbDsService.getDataSource())
ResultSet rs=sql.executeQuery("select top 5 Id from MACHINES  where (Total != Rightcount) order by FinishingTime");

order[0] = 0;
order[1] = 0;
order[2] = 0;
order[3] = 0;
count = 0;

while (rs.next())
 {
  order[count] = Integer.parseInt(rs["Id"].toString());
                           count = count + 1;
  }
```

Comment: What type is `Sql`? Which package are you using? Something like `import ...Sql`

Comment: import groovy.sql.*

Answer (score 0):

As per the message you're calling a protected method, the javadoc on the method states the following:

> Useful helper method which handles resource management when executing
>   a query which returns a result set. Derived classes of Sql can
>   override "createQueryCommand" and then call this method to access the
>   ResultSet returned from the provided query or alternatively can use
>   the higher-level method of Sql which return result sets which are
>   funnelled through this method, e.g. eachRow, query.

Instead try using something like eachRow

```
sql.eachRow("select top 5 Id from MACHINES  where (Total != Rightcount) order by FinishingTime") {
    order[count] = it.Id
    count = count + 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. It still did not work. And I did not get what does 'it.Id' does in the braces.

Comment: What does not work exactly? any errors? `it` is the default name used inside a groovy closure which provides access to whatever object is available in the closure, in this case the results from the query, I'm not 100% sure what your query returns, can you change the code in the {} to just print it so `{ println it }` so we're sure what, if anything is being returned

Comment: I get the error as "Cannot find matching method groovy.sql.Sql#eachRow(java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists. "

Comment: What version of groovy are you using? Are your imports correct & present? Also where/how are you running this?

Comment: Yes all the imports are correct and present. I am using groovy version 2.5.0-beta-2. I am running in eclipse.  My imports**                      import java.sql.ResultSet
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.*
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalTime

Comment: Bit lost with this TBH, if you can put something into github so we can grab and test locally that'd be useful, can you confirm that your the Sql constructor works okay? i.e. no errors & isn't null after creation?